# How to check NotEquals/Exists in Meteor Collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use a Meteor app to get documents from a mongodb database (using Meteor's Collection), but I only want documents that have a certain note field does not exist in it.

I tried to do:

```
Documents.findOne({id:'abcd',note:{"$exists":'true'}});
```

where documents is my Collection but it returns the first found result (which doesn't have a note field) rather than the one I need. I also tried using $exists but that doesn't work either.

Can someone please help me out here? I'm guessing I'm making a really silly error somewhere, but I just can't put my finger on it

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Documents.findOne({id:'abcd',note:{"$exists":true}});
```

Remember the `true` is parsed as a boolean in JSON only if it doesn't have encapsulated quotes

Comment: I knew it was a stupid mistake! Thanks! This worked great for me! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try taking out the quotes around $exists. Like

```
Documents.findOne({id: 'abcd', note:{ $exists: true}});
```

That should work.  Also, in case you didn't know, the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) are great for mongodb.

Comment: I'd tried this as well... but Akshat's answer worked for me! Thanks anyway Braden :)

Comment: Ah right, it should be just the boolean value and not a string.